# Problems with the function that determines when to start translation transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, scrollreveal.js

This question of mine derives from the lack of an openly exact or better approach than the others.
I have a single page html site and I want to implement a scroll reveal without using external libraries. In the case of top-to-bottom transitions, for example, the IntersectionObserver fires based on the position of the element moved for the transition and not based on its final position. This causes the animation to start as soon as the translated object enters the viewport and not when it actually scrolls to its final height. I need to figure out what approach to use for my function that detects when to initiate transitions.

My javascript now:

```
var elementiDaOsservare = document.querySelectorAll('.osservato');
var callback = function(items) {
    items.forEach((item) => {
        var position = item.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
            item.target.classList.add("mostrato");
        } else if (position.top > 0) { // rimuove la classe mostrato solo se l'item si trova nella parte non visibile superiore dello schermo
            item.target.classList.remove("mostrato");
        }
    });
}
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {threshold: 0.3});
elementiDaOsservare.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of 'top to bottom' transition, there isn't enough in the code you have given at the moment for us to help.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to make an example using just a few lines of code. Seems like a long enough thing to me. Just think of the title of the page which must start from -100px and arrive at its vertical position. In this case, the class will be added when the text translated by -100px is visible on the screen. Instead, I want it to be added when you actually get to the portion of the screen where the text is in its final position.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{ threshold: 1 }` in your IntersectionObserver so that the element gets isIntersecting only when 100% of it is visible.

Otherwise we also have `{ rootMargin: "-50px 0px" }`, which gives the element isIntersecting only when its extreme top reaches the point 50px from the bottom of the body & the element loses its isIntersecting when its extreme top goes above the point 50px from the top of the body.

I recommend you checking the full tutorial on IntersectionObserver from MDN.